# How to have different return values for multiple calls on a Jasmine spy

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

Say I'm spying on a method like this:

```
spyOn(util, "foo").andReturn(true);
```

The function under test calls `util.foo` multiple times.

Is it possible to have the spy return `true` the first time it's called, but return `false` the second time? Or is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You can use [spy.and.returnValues](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/SpyStrategy) (as Jasmine 2.4).

for example

```js
describe("A spy, when configured to fake a series of return values", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(util, "foo").and.returnValues(true, false);
  });

  it("when called multiple times returns the requested values in order", function() {
    expect(util.foo()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(util.foo()).toBeFalsy();
    expect(util.foo()).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

However, there is something you must be careful about. There is another function with a similar spelling: returnValue without s. If you use that, Jasmine will not warn you, but it will behave differently.

Comment: Doing it in the beforeEach was important for me, not in the test (it)

Comment: No need to worry about spelling errors when using jasmine in TypeScript, of course.

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper that's exactly why I visit this post.... again and again, and again :D

Comment: not working for me in jasmine@3.6.11

Answer (score 32):

For older versions of Jasmine, you can use [`spy.andCallFake`](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EandCallFake%3C/code%3E) for Jasmine 1.3 or [`spy.and.callFake`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E) for Jasmine 2.0, and you'll have to keep track of the 'called' state, either through a simple closure, or object property, etc.

```
var alreadyCalled = false;
spyOn(util, "foo").andCallFake(function() {
    if (alreadyCalled) return false;
    alreadyCalled = true;
    return true;
});
```

Comment: We can extend this for more than 2 calls like so:

var results = [true, false, "foo"];
var callCount = 0;
spyOn(util, "foo").and.callFake(function() {
    return results[callCount++];
});

Comment: This can be extended into a generic function like so: 
function returnValues() { var args = arguments; var callCount = 0; return function() { return args[callCount++]; }; }

Comment: Why whole this code when you can just return results.shift() ?

Comment: how about when we return observabvles

Comment: this option is more flexible, as we can throw error or return value depending on the call order.