# Jasmine-Jquery - return different async content for different calls to spyOn

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to return different values on multiple `sypOn` calls in `Jasmine 1.4.1`.  I have the following code based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898613/how-to-have-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls-on-a-jasmine-spy):

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
    loadFixtures('fixture.html');
    spyOn(dynamicContent, 'get').and.returnValues($ver1.getHtml(done),      
                                                  $ver2.getHtml(done));        
});
```

**EDIT**

I realise the above is for Jasmine 2.4 and above.

I also tried the other answers for older version but I get the same issue.

```
 var alreadyCalled = false;
    spyOn(dynamicContent, "get").and.callFake(function() {
       if (alreadyCalled) return $ver1.getHtml(done);
       alreadyCalled = true;
       return $ver2.getHtml(done);    
  });
```

I should point out that I'm using `jasmine-jquery`.

My `getHtml` functions look like this and are identical for test purposes:

```
 function getHtml(done) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();     
    $.get('some.html').then(function (data) {
        // will only make it this far for the first call to getHtml()
        deferred.resolve(data);          
        done();
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

The problem is that only the first call to `spyOn` succeeds.

I'm wondering if it is due to the way I pass `done` to the function and resolve it within getHtml()

How can I make sure both `async` calls get returned on subsequent calls to the spy?

Comment: your question title says jasmine **2** but the content says **1.4.1**, which is the right one?

Comment: Title says SypOn - it can help if you change it to SpyOn.